# Domain name for an IBM Cloud Code Engine application

Tags: domains

I have created an application using IBM Cloud Code Engine. I have domain names. How do I configure a domain name for the application for no cost or reasonable cost?

I have found [Deploying an app across multiple regions with a custom domain name | IBM Cloud Docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-deploy-multiple-regions) but IBM Cloud Internet Services costs at least $275 a month (after trial).

I have found [Adding and using a custom domain | IBM Cloud Docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-custom-domains) but as best as I understand that, Cloud Foundry is different from Code Engine.

I am experienced with configuring DNS for domain names. I just need the documentation of configuring a domain name specific to an IBM Cloud Code Engine application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no "built-in" way to configure custom domains for Code Engine, but it's a widely requested feature and we are currently working on it. However, we have no committed release date for it yet. Until we have native support for custom URLs in Code Engine, you have two options.

The first is going via CIS, which you have already found in the documentation. It's mostly suitable for our large enterprise customers and might not be cost-effective for individual developers.

For those, we would suggest signing up for the free plan at Cloudflare.com and then allowing Cloudflare to manage your custom domain. You then deploy a worker that points to the domain running on Code Engine. This approach is free of charge and comes with additional advantages (e.g. DDOS protection) for your site. Here are the step-by-step instructions on how to do it: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-ibm-cloud-code-engine-application

Uwe

P.S. Only stumbled across this by chance, in the future you might want to use StackOverflow and use the ibm-cloud-code-engine tag : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud-code-engine

Comment: Thank you. I have set up Cloudflare but the domain is getting SSL errors. I assume I need to modify the Code Engine configuration to solve that. When I have that problem solved I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: You need to set up an actual edge function to re-direct the traffic. The blog post should be out in the next few days, describing the process in detail

Comment: Added link to tutorial

Comment: This question was originally asked at StackOverflow but it was closed as off-topic there because it is not a programming question. Non programming questions about running websites with ibm cloud compute engine can be asked here.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think you are referring to a question that is similar but for IBM Cloud Object Storage. I do not know if the procedure in the IBM article will work for Object Storage. The important thing is that the topic is appropriate here and not StackOverflow.